# Polymorph vs Relation Mysql with Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

My case is this:

I have 2 solutions for my database:

1. One table of **Address** with polimorph
2. One table of **Address** with relations to another tables

For give more details about this, in sumary my tables has this columns:

## Case Polymorph - without relation

**Address Table:**

```
AddressId INT
Address VARCHAR(...) - Street, Number....
OwnerType VARCHAR(...) - Type of owner informed Address, like **Customer**
OwnerId INT - Id of owner, in this case **CustumerId**
```

**Customer Table:**

```
CustumerId 
CustumerName VARCHAR(...)
```

## Case Relation - Many to Many

**Address Table:**

```
AddressId INT
Address VARCHAR(...) - Street, Number....
```

**Customer Table:**

```
CustumerId 
CustumerName VARCHAR(...)
```

**CostumerAddress Table: (relation M2M)**

```
CustumerId INT
AddressId INT
```

## Question

Both cases give me all address of custumers, in Many to Many scenario.
But who is better?
I need **pros** and **cons** for both cases.

thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question should be partly found in asking yourself "What do I need?".

As I understand it, the polymorphic approach that you outlined is a `one to many` relationship that will only allow a owner/customer to have many addresses whereas the `many to many` approach will allow a owner/customer to have many addresses and an address to have many owner/customers. So be aware you are looking at two different types: `one to many` (polymorphic) or `many to many`.

The benefit in using a polymorphic approach *generally* is that you're not limited to what type of model another model is related to on one side of the relationship. This provides greater flexibility and for example in your scenario, will save you creating multiple `addresses` tables per model that requires an address.

For example, if you had a `customers` table that was linked to a `customer_addresses` table and a `owners` table linked to a `owner_addresses` table, you could solve this duplication using a polymorphic relationship by having one `addresses` table that links to either the `owners` or `customers` table by having a column representing either table/model and the accompanying primary key for the table/model.

Check the docs for further details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

You can also have `many to many` polymorphic relationships in laravel, see the docs for further details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 1):

It depends...

if your business role support many address to many customers, implements many to many.

If not, polymorph is better.

- Owner -> base class
- Owner extends Address
- Customer extends Owner

I hope I've helped =]